# Normals flipped when exporting to FBX?

Tags: export, import, normals

I'm running the latest version of blender. Almost every time I export a model into FBX, the normals of the imported model become flipped. I've been looking up how to solve this, but nothing seems to work; Negative scales turned positive don't change it, and all the normals on the model I'm exporting are facing the right direction. I have absolutely no clue why this is doing it, and all the solutions I've seen online don't seem to help me at all. Can anyone help with this?[image]

Comment: are you sure  the normal are flipped? Sometimes it's just a material problem. And make sure the scale is applied before you export

Comment: @Alex you were right! It was so annoying - the settings for the material were wonky when importing. Oh well, now I know to look there in future. Thank you!

Comment: In the material settings, check if "show backface" is on.